# Activate iMessages/Messages Application in VMWare MAC OS Environment

Tags: macos, vmware, imessage

I'm using MAC OS 10.11 El Capitan via Oracle VMWare Virtualbox (5.0.26). I have setup whole environment based on Windows10.

**MAC OS working very well with Oracle VMWare Virtualbox BUT iMessages/Messages application not working with APPLE ID.**

**I want to Activate/Used iMessages/Messages application using APPLE ID.**

I have done R&D on web and Applied suggested patches on Oracle VMWare environment but not succeed. PLEASE let me know your suggestions.

**VMWare environment details:**

1) VMWare Virtualbox 5.0.26

2) MAC OS 10.11 El Capitan

3) Window 10

Thank in Advance!!!

**Reference Links:**

https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-pc

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changedmi

https://superuser.com/questions/55561/how-can-i-change-the-bios-serial-number-in-virtualbox

https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/how-to-fix-imessage.110471/

https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/525dsb/getting_imessage_working_on_el_capitan_and_sierra/

https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/2wohwn/getting_imessage_working_on_10102_generating/

https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-pc-on-virtualbox/

http://www.fitzweekly.com/2016/02/hackintosh-imessage-tutorial.html

https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/32602-Mac-OS-X-El-Capitan-No-Serial-Port-Solution-inside